# gcloud pubsub subscriptions COMMAND "PURGE MESSAGES"

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud, google-cloud-pubsub

In GCP console you have the possibility to purge messages in a subscription.
It looks like "gcloud pubsub subscriptions" do not support a "PURGE MESSAGES" command.
What are the best alternatives are there any other libraries or API?

Answer (score 4):

With `gcloud` tool this functionality is provided by the [seek](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/pubsub/subscriptions/seek) method. It effectively resets a subscription's backlog to a point in time or to a given snapshot. So, to purge all messages from a subscription you'd pass the current time via the `--time` flag, for example:

```
gcloud pubsub subscriptions seek my_subscription__name --time=2022-02-10T11:00:00Z
```

Messages in the subscription that were published before this time are marked as acknowledged, and messages retained in the subscription that were published after this time are marked as unacknowledged.

The equivalent API endpoint for it is [projects.subscriptions.seek](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.subscriptions/seek).